# Android Listview make button invisible in getview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview with custom adapter which extends Baseadapter. In each row of listview i have a textview and a button, by default the button is in Invisible state. I am calling view.OntouchListener in getView method of Adapter,when the row gets swiped i am making button Visible at that position. when the other row get swiped all the buttons in other rows should get Invisible except the current position one.

Any help is Appreciated.

Thanks,
Prashanth.

Comment: You should provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to keep the visibility state of a button in adapter. 
Below you I added an example (not tested yet) about how to show the button when the text is clicked (any other buttons will be hidden).

import com.test.data.ExportOption;

public class ExportOptionsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

```
// Constants
private final static String TAG = "ExportOptionsAdapter";

// Data
private ArrayList<ExportOption> mItems;
private Context mContext; 
private LayoutInflater mLf;
private ListView mParent;

public ExportOptionsAdapter(Context pContext) {
    mItems = new ArrayList<ExportOption>(); 
    mContext = pContext;
    mLf = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public ExportOptionsAdapter add(ExportOption pOption){
    mItems.add(pOption);
    return this;
}

public ExportOptionsAdapter add(ArrayList<ExportOption> exportOptions) {
    mItems.addAll(exportOptions);
    return this;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}

public ExportOption getItem(int position) {
    return mItems.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder vh;

    if(null == mParent){
        mParent = (ListView) parent;
    }

    if(null == convertView){
        convertView = (View)mLf.inflate(R.layout.export_option, parent, false);
        vh = new ViewHolder();
        vh.option = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_name);
        vh.btn = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn);


        convertView.setTag(vh);
    } else {
        vh = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    vh.option.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = mParent.getPositionForView(v);
            if(AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION != position){                   
                for(int i = 0; i < mItems.size(); i++){
                    if(i == position){
                        // mark the selected one as visible
                        mItems.get(position).markButtonAsVisible(true);
                    } else {
                        // hide the other items
                        mItems.get(position).markButtonAsVisible(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    vh.option.setText(mItems.get(position).getType());

    if(mItems.get(position).buttonMarkedAsVisible()){
        vh.btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        vh.btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder{
    public TextView option;
    public Button btn;
}
```

}